# Function to read web via JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am getting this error while trying to write a function which returns an `NSDictionary` after reading data using JSON:

> Cannot convert the expression's type NSDictionary? to type Void

```
func readJsonData() -> NSDictionary{
        let urlPath = "http://www.telize.com/geoip"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler:{(data , response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil){
                    println(error)
                }else{
                    let jsonresult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
                    return jsonresult
                }
            })
       task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Question: Why do you think there is an error parameter in the method `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `completionHandler` has a return type of `Void` but you are returning `jsonresult` which is of type `NSDictionary`.

You should remove the line:

```
return jsonresult
```

As you should not return a value to a completion handler.

If you want to set a variable in your class on the completion, you can execute a thread on the main queue and set the variable equal to jsonresult:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler:{(data , response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil){
                    println(error)
                }else{
                    let jsonresult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.jsonData = jsonresult
                    //Update GUI, etc.
                    })  
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how can I return jsonresult from my function?

Comment: See my update. You need to execute code back on the main queue to update your GUI or variables. You can even call a function in your class and pass it the resulting data.

Comment: I am sorry to say that it is still not working for me. I put println(jsondata) at the end of function and its still not returning anything.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the way you are getting your data. Check to see if your data has any values. Although I will shy away from discussion on this since it is off topic of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to learn how an asynchronous call works. Your function readJsonData cannot work that way.

You call dataTaskWithURL. The call returns immediately, without any result. That's why readJsonData *cannot* return a dictionary. However, the data that dataTaskWithURL downloads arrives a long time later (100s of milliseconds, or seconds, or maybe a minute). When the data arrives, your callback function is called. The callback cannot return anything because its call has long since returned. The callback must deliver the data to whoever wants it.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. So if I understood it correctly there is no way I can return a dictionary. I have to performa whatever task is required in my closure itself which in my case is writing to Core Data. Is that correct?